# Incompatible type for argument and uninitialised in this function

Tags: c

I am having an issue with one/two of my methods when I am calling it in `main()` and I'm unsure why.

```
int main()
{
    struct list * list;

    list_init(list);

    while(TRUE)
    {
        struct book book1;
    
        printf("Enter title of book: ");
        if(!getInput(book1.title, sizeof(book1.title)))
        {
            break;
        }
    
        printf("Enter author of book: ");
        if(!getInput(book1.author, sizeof(book1.author)))
        {
            break;
        }
    
        printf("Enter dewey code of book: ");
        if(!getInput(book1.deweycode, sizeof(book1.deweycode)))
        {
            break;
        }
    
        printf("Enter publisher code of book: ");
        if(!getInput(book1.publisher, sizeof(book1.publisher)))
        {
            break;
        }
    
        printf("Enter ISBN code of book: ");
        if(!getInput(book1.isbn, sizeof(book1.isbn)))
        {
            break;
        }
    
    list_add(list, &book1);
    
    printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n");

    printf("Printing Linked List \n");
    printList(list);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The error I receive with this code is:

> "incompatible type for argument 2 of 'list_add'"
>
> "expected 'struct book *' but argument is of type 'struct book'".

I've tried to relieve this issue but changing `book1` to `&book1` as was suggested on another question but when I do so I get a warning:

> "`list` is uninitialised in this function".

Here is where I am supposed to be initialising `list`.

```
void list_init(struct list * list)
{
    list = malloc(sizeof(*list));
    if(list != NULL)
    {
        list->head = NULL;
        list->num_books = 0;
    }
}
```

And this is the book struct:

```
struct book
{
    char title[TITLELEN+1];
    char author[AUTHORLEN+1];
    char deweycode[DDCLEN+1];
    char publisher[PUBLEN+1];
    char isbn[ISBNLEN+1];
};
```

Can anyone please help and explain why list is not being initialized? I have also tried `list * list = malloc(sizeof(*list))` but that gives me another error.

Comment: If you are not going to return a the node from `list_init`, then you need to pass the address of `list` to `list_init` (e.g. `void list_init(struct list **list)`. It is far better to do both in my opinion to provide the flexibility to assign the return in the caller, or simply pass the address of the list. (this is required because the *address of the first node* is the *address of the list* which you currently have no way to return from `list_init`) You can do `list *list_init(struct list **list)` while returning `list` to cover both basis.

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem is in your `list_init()` function. In that function, `list` is local to the function and any changes made to `list` itself will not reflected to the caller function argument.

*Note: C uses pass-by-value for function parameter passing, so any changes made to the parameters themselves inside the function will not be reflected back to the argument in the caller function.*

Now in your `main()` code, `list` is an uninitialized local variable and after the call to `list_init(list);` it still remains uninitialized, which your compiler is **rightly** complaining about.

You need to either

- pass a pointer to the `list` variable in `main()`, accept it as a pointer to pointer to `struct list` (i.e., `struct list ** list`), allocate memory using `malloc()` to `*list`.
- return the pointer to newly allocated memory to the caller ans assign it back to the actual pointer. You'll be needing to change the return type of `list_init()` in that case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Just to clarify that I'm doing everything correctly. You want me to change struct list * list to struct list ** list in main() and in my function list_init() which means I also have to change list = malloc(sizeof(*(list)) to list * list = malloc(sizeof(*list))?

Comment: @C.Smith No, in `main()` you can keep `struct list * list;`, just call `list_init(&list);`, change the function signature to `void list_init(struct list * *list)` and then do `* list = malloc(sizeof(**list))`

Comment: Ooooh, yes. I've done that but now I have another error that appears... "request for member 'head' in something not a structure or union". I haven't come across an error like that before.

Comment: @C.Smith OK, that goes without saying, you have to replace _all_ the `lists` with `*list`. Check the data type.

Comment: I have done that and it creates a lot more errors than before. However, what I'm most concerned about is that the compiler has an issue with "*list->head" and even if I change that to  "*list.head" there is still an issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Issue:1:**
Change the return type of  `list_init`

```
struct list* list_init()
{
    list = malloc(sizeof(*list));
    if(list != NULL)
    {
        list->head = NULL;
        list->num_books = 0;
    }
    return list;
}
```

And call it this way in `main()`

```
int main() {

    struct list * list;

    list = list_init();
```

---

**Issue:2:**

After this another issue is that in while loop every time you are taking local copy of book and using that pointer in list_add()

```
    struct book book1;
```

I suggest to malloc every time, SO for every entry you will have seperate copy of book

Comment: Correct, but _why_ do I need to do that? :)